# Handling multiple Ordered Data Store requests

Tags: roblox, luau

I’m trying to script one of those Time Trial games, the thing is they have leaderboards which require them to request data for multiple stages at the same time after time intervals. I’m coding something similar, I have 10 stages, however after a little bit of time these warnings start popping up and the leaderboard stops updating:

[image: https://doy2mn9upadnk.cloudfront.net/uploads/default/original/4X/b/0/5/b05c0d4872254f22109131832cbb0b8b1e43541e.png]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs on [DataStore Errors and Limits](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Data-store#Limits).

> When a limit is reached, further requests are placed into one of four queues: set, ordered set, get, and ordered get. Requests in a queue are handled in the order they are received and the called function continues to yield as long as its request is queued. If the data store key itself is throttled, the request is temporarily skipped but still in the queue. Each queue has a limit of 30 requests and, when this limit is exceeded, the requests fail with an error code in the 301–306 range indicating that the request was dropped entirely.

As the warnings imply, you're sending too many requests. You need to find a way to read / write / update data less frequently.

Comment: Yeah, I know that much, but how exactly do I do that? The task requires there to be multiple requests to be sent at the same time.

Comment: Try only updating the data when the player leaves the game, or every couple stages. Or check how long it has been since your last save, and if it has been less than 30 second to a minute, then don't save.